# Excel: Automate copying a value a number of times equivalent to the Count of non-zero cells in the same row

Tags: vba, excel

As my dataset is quite large (thousands of rows and dozens of columns), I would like to automate the process of:

1. copying a given ID# a number of times equivalent to the Count of non-zero cells (parents) in its row (excluding the ID# itself), and
2. adding the parent# in question to a cell adjacent to the copied ID#.
3. Ignore all parents with cells equal to zero.

**Example:**

My dataset possesses ID numbers in Column A. Each ID# possesses multiple parents in its own row. ID# 1 in Cell A2 possesses 4x nonzero parent numbers 265, 266, 32 and 7, in B2, C2, D2 and E2 respectively. Cell F2 = zero, and should be ignored.

[image: Current data format: Parents per ID#]

**Desired output in another sheet:**

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do what you want.

Change the sheet names to match the sheet names you have.

```
Sub Sortstuff()

Dim ows As Worksheet
Dim tws As Worksheet
Dim trw&
Dim cel as range

Set ows = Worksheets("Sheet1") 'original sheet
Set tws = Worksheets("Sheet2") 'target sheet

For Each cel In ows.Range(ows.Range("B2"), ows.Range("B2").End(xlDown).End(xltoRight))
    If cel <> 0 Then
        trw = tws.Range("A" & tws.Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
        tws.Cells(trw, 2) = ows.Cells(cel.Row, 1)
        tws.Cells(trw, 1) = cel.value
    End If
Next

End Sub
```